# OAuth2 with SPA + REST API

Tags: rest, spring-boot, oauth, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

Lets say we have SPA written in Angular 2 and have REST API using Spring Boot.
Both of them deployed in different servers. And now I have to protect this API via Facebook's OAuth2, but I don't know which grant type suits to my problem.

I don't want to be an auth server, I don't want facebook to be my resource server, instead my own REST API is supposed to be a resource server. 
From FB I just want username or email or some identifier.

If I understood correctly I have to use implicit grant flow, because it's not a web application, correct me please, if I'm wrong.
Does "authorization code" grant also could be a choice ?

I really read almost all the threads related to oauth, spring security..
But I didn't find any info related to exactly SPA and REST API for separate servers.

Any link/resource related to above problem is appreciated.

Thanks in advance and sorry if I did something wrong, it's my very first post here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement Implicit Grant flow https://oauth2.thephpleague.com/authorization-server/implicit-grant/

you need HTTPS for safety.

example:

- OAuth Server: https://myoauthserver.com
- restapi: https://myrestapi.com
- client: https://myclient.com

send a get request to oauthserver "authorize" url with params

- response_type = token (sometimes 'code')
- redirect_uri = myclient.com or myclient.com/something (the one u assign while making an oauth client )
- client id = dfuvhiurehvher (whatever id)

some providers require additional parameters like "scope".

when you send a request if everything works. you will be redirected to your client with the token in the url.

your request:

- GET: https://myoauthserver.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=token&redirect_uri=https://myclient.com&client_id=yourClientIdHere

if successful you'll be redirected to

- https://myclient.com?token=yourTokenValueIsHere

you can now use javascript to retrieve and store token value maybe to localStorage and attach it when sending requests to restapi (https://myrestapi.com)

heres an example request from auth0.com

```
  $.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: "http://localhost:7001/api/appointments",
    headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer " + ATTACH_YOUR_TOKEN_VALUE_HERE }
  });
```

for more details check this 
https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/implicit-grant